# Import Module Error when building a Docker Container with Python for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a Docker container that runs Python code on AWS Lambda. The build works fine, but when I test my code, I get the following error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'function': No module named 'utils'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

I basically have two python scripts in my folder, function.py and utils.py, and I import some functions from utils.py and use them in function.py.

Locally, it all works fine, but when I build the Container and test it with the following curl command, I get the above error. Test curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"Input": 4}'
```

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

COPY function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD [ "function.lambda_handler" ]
```

What I read in related Stackoverflow questions is to try importing the functions from utils.py in another way, I've tried changing `from utils import *` to `from .utils import all`, I changed the WORKDIR in my Dockerfile, and I put the utils file in a separate utils folder and tried importing this way: `from utils.utils import *`. I have also tried running the code in Python 3.8.

Here's my folder structure: [Here's my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgpN0.png)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}` ? Shouldn't you be copying `utils.py` there too?

Comment: The `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}` I got from the AWS tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html).

I didn't try explicitly copying the utils.py before (I thought this would be included in `COPY . .`?), but I just tried it anyway and got the same error :/

Comment: `COPY . .` would copy all files to the workdir directory, which is `/`, while you want to copy the file to `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`

Comment: Can you show the imports in `function.py` in the question?

Comment: Got it, thank you! Getting new errors now, so at least that one seems to be solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfile statement `COPY . .` copies all files to the working directory, which given your previous `WORKDIR`, is `/`.

To resolve the Python import issue, you need to move the Python module to the right directory:

```
COPY utils.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```